# How to create Google Calendar events on behalf of another user?

Tags: security, authentication, google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

I'd like to implement a scheduling application where Person X can create an event at a specific time add it to their Google Calendar. Then Person Y should be able to sign up for that same event and get it added to their Google Calendar. Person X should also be able to reschedule the event as well. I'm having some trouble understanding how to design this, and would appreciate some pointers.

So Person X can authenticate on the client side and create the event, but then the server would need to store that event ID so that Person Y can sign up. But how does the server invite Person Y on behalf of Person X? I'm trying to authenticate using a service account but I'm getting `There was an error contacting the Calendar service: Error: Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority.` when I try creating an invite server-side and adding attendees. This seems like a fundamental issue where service accounts can't invite random attendees unless they're in a GSuite domain.

Applications like Calendly can basically do this (you can sign up on someone else's calendar then get invited to a Google Calendar event they organized), so I'm sure this is doable.

Here's my basic test code: this works without the `attendees` field, but fails with the aforementioned error if it's set.

```js
import { google } from 'googleapis'
import * as SERVICE_ACCOUNT from './service-account.json'

const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';

const auth = new google.auth.JWT(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT.client_email,
    null,
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT.private_key,
    SCOPES
)

console.log("Testing Google Calendar API")

const api = google.calendar({version : "v3", auth : auth})

api.events.insert({
    calendarId: '{CALENDAR}@group.calendar.google.com',
    requestBody: { 
        summary: 'Dope Test Event',
        description: 'Wow this works!',
        start: { dateTime: '2020-12-28T09:00:00-07:00', timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles' },
        end: { dateTime: '2020-12-28T10:00:00-07:00', timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles' },
        attendees: [
            { email: '{EMAIL}@gmail.com' } // works without this
        ] 
    }},
    function (err, res) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log(res)
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says:

> Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority.

So, you need to set-up domain-wide delegation which would allow a service account to impersonate a user - that is act on a user's behalf.

**To set-up domain-wide delegation:**

- In the GCP console, tick the checkbox `Enable G Suite Domain-wide Delegation` for the service account you are using by going on `Actions-> Edit`
- [Enable the necessary scopes](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account) for the delegating service acocunt in your admin console by going on  `Security > API controls.`
  Modify your code as following:

```js
const auth = new google.auth.JWT(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT.client_email,
    null,
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT.private_key,
    SCOPES,
    USER_EMAIL 
)
```

whereby `USER_EMAIL` is the email fo the domain user that shall be impersonated by the service account.

Recommended reading:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests

Comment: Ah I think I was misunderstanding domain-wide delegation - we were able to figure this out!

Comment: Just wondering, this works like a charm, but the emails sent from the account I'm impersonating have a weird display name like `:kf` or something (it changes, but it's always a colon and two letters). How do I set this?

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49011887/g-suite-account-missing-displayname-parameter-in-calendar-api) is helpful.